# how to make input text display format as decimal format 0.00

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am using an `<input type="text">` to give employee's working hours. I want to show the text format as `0.00` and make it to accept only two digits and two decimal digits only as decimal format.

```html
<td>
     <input type="text" asp-for="NormalHrs" class="col-sm-5" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) ||event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 0 " />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a Validate method to check whether the entered value is validated or not, if not clear the value and entered again, else format the data.

Code as below:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="NormalHrs" placeholder="0.00" value="" class="col-sm-5" maxlength="5" 
       onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) ||event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 0 " 
       onfocusout ="validateinput(this)"
       /> 
<script> 
    function validateinput(el) {
        if (parseFloat(el.value) < 99 & parseFloat(el.value)>0) {
            el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);
        }
        else {
            //show invalidate message.
            //clear the input value.
            el.value = "";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this this js,

first make an event(focusout/onclick which one you like)

input type should be 'number'

```
<input type="number" onfocusout="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" step="0.01" value="0.00"/>

function setTwoNumberDecimal(el) {
        el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example I think will meet all your requirements. It sets a number of validation rules for the browser to check. The example only allows numbers to be entered and configures the allowed minimum, maximum and how detailed the input can be.

A user could enter 00007.22 but if you treat it as a number on the server or trim leading zeroes its not a problem. Do not forget to perform server-side validation as well, you should never put to much trust on the client.

```html
<form action="/post">
    <label>Fill in your working time: </label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="8" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```